# CKEditor 4.5.4 - changes asterisk to bullets

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have a lot of content that have asterisks in them. Ckeditor changes them all to bullets. How do I prevent this and to have ckeditor always show asterisks as asterisks and never change them to bullets? Thanks in advance.